# How to get the data from function inside one file to another file

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, python-import, python-module

I have to import some value from one file to another file. I have a function name myFunc in second.py where i have a variable name 'a'. Now I want to display this value in first.py file inside main function.

```
first.py
-------
import os
import second.py import *

def main():
    //here i need to print from another file


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

second.py
---------
import os

def myFunc(var1, var2):
    a = 'test user'
```

Comment: You can make a class in the second.py and then declare the variable a. Then in first.py you can create an object for that class and should be able to access the variable.

Comment: @San can you give me an example

Comment: You can't really pull a variable out from inside a function like that (even in the case of a single file).   If `myFunc` *returned* `a`, you could write, in first.py: `print(myFunc(..., ...))` and since `myFunc` returned `a`, it would be printed when you ran first.py.

Answer (score 1):

Try returning `a` in second.py:

```
import os

def myFunc(var1, var2):
    a = 'test user'
    return a
```

Then try the below code in first.py

```
import os
import second

def main():
    print(second.myFunc(something,something))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

*Note: something is where you should fill in the argument (meaning the `var1` and `var2`)*

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example of what i suggested in the comments.

**first.py**

```
import os
from second import first_class

def main():
    obj = first_class()
    print(obj.a)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**second.py**

```
import os

class first_class:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 'test user'
```

Hope it helps !!

Comment: I get obj = first_class()
NameError: global name 'first_class' is not defined

Comment: @user1687891 sorry, i missed to keep parenthesis at class definition, please check the updated code.

Comment: yes i have used parenthesis in my code , but it says same error.

Comment: @Dux Thanks for the edit Bud !!. Donno what i was thinking when i wrote that import statement.

Comment: @user1687891 please find the updated import statement. It should be working now.

Comment: @San, happens to me all the time ;)

Answer (score 0):

when you define a function the variables that were inside it are outside the global scope therefore they are only accessible within that function, if you want to obtain a value of that function you return it a solution to your problem could be the following

## second.py

```
import os
def myFunc(var1, var2):
    a = 'test user';
    return a
```